# Azure IOT hub - respond to missing device data

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-iot-hub

I have an IOT hub with devices that push their sensor data to it, to be stored in a SQL database. I would like to receive an alert when any device does not push data to the hub within its usual interval (or when no new data arrives in the database, that is).

When I select the IoT Hub in Azure, I see a section about Monitoring -> Alerts. But in this configuration section, I cannot find some setting to be used for such an alert. 
Usually the devices push every 15 minutes. Ideally, I would like to receive a mail when a device has not pushed data for 1 hour. 
Would that be possible by configuration? Or do I need to write a Function App that queries the database and compares timestamps? I cannot imagine that Azure does not have a solution for this problem.

[image: Azure IoT Hub config]

Comment: The Azure Stream Analytics job can help you for this scenario. The output job can triggered a HttpTrigger function for sending an email.

Comment: @Roman Kiss thanks for your suggestion, but in that way I will receive an e-mail when the IoT Hub does have output. I would like to receive an e-mail (or some other notification) when one or more devices fail to push data (i.e., when no data arrives in ASA for that device), or am I missing something?

Comment: have a look at this solution: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/paolos/2015/12/17/how-to-find-absence-of-signal-in-a-stream-analytics-job/